# How to set a flatbuffers table field with bytes array

Tags: python, flatbuffers

I want set a flatbuffers table field with bytes value.

What I have managed so far, without success, it is the following.

### flatbuffers schema:

```
namespace sint.bl;

table Response {
    id:short;
    body:[byte];
}
```

### python sample code:

```
import flatbuffers
import pickle
import sint.bl.Request
import sint.bl.Response

my_dict = {
        'a': 1
}

my_bytes = pickle.dumps(my_dict)

builder = flatbuffers.Builder(1024)

sint.bl.Response.ResponseStart(builder)
sint.bl.Response.ResponseAddId(builder, 100)

# this line throws the exception:
# ValueError: invalid literal for int() 
# with base 10: b'\x80\x03}q\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01K\x01s.'
sint.bl.Response.ResponseAddBody(builder, my_bytes)

response = sint.bl.Response.ResponseEnd(builder)

builder.Finish(response)

response_pdu = builder.Output()
```

What is it the correct way to manage bytes encoded fields with flatbuffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `ResponseAddBody` is an offset to the serialized byte vector (the `int` in your error), not the `bytes` object directly. This needs to be serialized *before* the table.

So, right after you create `builder`, call `builder.CreateByteVector(my_bytes)`, the result of which you pass to `ResponseAddBody` later.

Alternatively, here's how to create any vector manually (select Python, search for `inventory`): https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html

Note, you appear to be using 2 serialization systems, pickle and FlatBuffers. You'd be better off encoding the picked data directly in FlatBuffers, using e.g. `table Foo { a:int }` instead of your dict, or if it has to be an open-ended dict, a vector of `table KeyValue { key:string; value:int; }` or similar. Or a union, depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. On the side of decoding is there a method to get back the entire bytes array? The only example I've found is an index access like `monster.Inventory(2)`.

Comment: There's `InventoryAsNumpy` but not for regular byte arrays it seems. Open an issue on github, or better yet, a PR.